# Get the mode of a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix that is 300x50 big filled with integers. I want to find what number appears the most in that 300x50 matrix and have it returned as an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`mode`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mode.html) on the [linearized](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?s_tid=doc_12b#f1-85511) matrix:

```
mode(matrix(:))
```

Example:

```
>> matrix = [3 2 3; 2 2 1]
matrix =

     3     2     3
     2     2     1

>> mode(matrix(:))
ans =
     2
```

Comment: Simple and Elegant. 

Thank you.

Comment: @Luis Mendo, I'm unhappy with this question being closed. It is not very smart, but it is not off-topic. What do you think? Would it make sense to try to reopen it?

Comment: @A.Donda I'm not sure... I wouldn't have voted to close it, but I understand why people have done so. It really doesn't demonstrate a minimal understanding, and doesn't include attempted solutions